# C# Visual Studio Not Building in current project only

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, build, compilation

I have a program that I have been writing and I usually press F6 to build and then CTRL + F5 to run the program. I must have hit something because in my current project nothing is ever updated when I press F6. I get the following message in the Output:

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ===========

I have since copied and pasted all of this code into a new project and F6 followed by CTRL + F5 builds and runs my program without issue, updating my code as I expected, which leaves me to believe this is a project specific issue, not Visual Studio specific issue, as it's only effecting this one project.

Any idea what I must have hit that is causing this issue and what I can do to fix it? I obviously have a work around that gets me by, but this isn't the first time I've done this and I'd love to know how to fix it so that I don't have to copy all of my code and recreate it all from scratch each time.

As a reference, I've already tried resetting my keyboard shortcuts to default (though I wouldn't think that would be the case since it works on other projects, unless keyboard shortcuts are project specific, which I doubt). I've also checked under BUILD > Configuration Manager to make sure that Build is checked, which it is. Those are the only two solutions I have come across when searching for this issue online, though it's possible I'm using the wrong keywords when searching.

I appreciate any insight anyone can offer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Build solution** will only perform an incremental build that means, projects in the solution that are not changed will be ignored during build process. Instead you can perform **Rebuild solution** (found in Build menu) which will completely build the solution from scratch. This is probably what you want

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my issue! I appreciate the quick response and I learned a bit more about compiling in the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the solution and Rebiuld it.
If does not work , close the solution and exit the Visual Studio and Restart it,

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error now and upon rebuilding it showed successful but when I try to run it disappears and there is no solution window.

I have successfully built a custom control and I have dragged it to the windows form application and it is successfully working. Code is completly fine but the main issue is I can not see the solution - as it is never updated.

Let me know if I am doing something wrong.